# Entity Framework and the repository pattern

Tags: entity-framework

I want to use entity framework to persist domain entites. My Project is setup as follows:-

- UI: MVC (Uses Automapper to map between domain entities and view models)
- Domain: Entites, Services, Repository Interfaces
- Repository: Entity Framework (implementing the interfaces from the domain layer). Uses Automapper to map between domain entities and Entity framework objects.

This works well, except when in my service if I do something like validate an item by checking the repository, then performing an update. This fails because Entity Frameworks identity map has seen the item before, and I try and attach it again.

I can work around this issue using code as follows (this would be made more generic)

```
        public void Update(Domain.Entities.Book entity)
    {
        Book newBook = _mapper.Map<Domain.Entities.Book, Book>(entity);
        ObjectStateEntry cacheEntry;
        if (_dataContext.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(_dataContext.CreateEntityKey("Books",newBook), out cacheEntry))
        {
            _dataContext.Books.ApplyCurrentValues(newBook);
        }
        else
        {
            _dataContext.Books.Attach(newBook);
            _dataContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(newBook, EntityState.Modified);
        }
        _dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The problem is I find my self having to write the same sort of code for deletions

```
        public void Delete(Domain.Entities.Book entity)
    {
        Book newBook = _mapper.Map<Domain.Entities.Book, Book>(entity);
        ObjectStateEntry cacheEntry;
        if (_dataContext.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(_dataContext.CreateEntityKey("Books", newBook), out cacheEntry))
        {
            _dataContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(cacheEntry.Entity, EntityState.Deleted);

        }
        else
        {
            _dataContext.Books.Attach(newBook);
            _dataContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(newBook, EntityState.Deleted);
        }
        _dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I'm sure there must be a better way of achieving what I'm trying to do, but I can't for the life of me figure out what!

Any other general comments about the above approach would be appreciated to as I'm about to use it on a large scale project!

Thanks

Ross

Comment: I'm wondering how you can come into a situation that you don't know if an entity is already attached or not. The use of an advanced method like `TryGetObjectStateEntry` in a basic use case like updating an entity is a code smell in my opinion. Also be aware that your update relies on the assumption that `cacheEntry.Entity` represents the original state in the DB, otherwise `ApplyCurrentValues` and change tracking won't mark the correct properties as modified to perform the correct DB UPDATE. Do you know that always when you even don't know if the entity is already attached or not?

Comment: Creating the repository object and getting an items causes the item to be loaded into EF, then translated into a domain item. This domain item could then be edited then past to the repositories update method. This domain object would then (using AutoMap) be turned into a detached EF object. Attaching this to EF would cause an exception as the key has already been saved. I'm surprised this isn't a bigger issue for people?

Comment: I see. But why do you distinguish between "domain entities" and "EF entities"? Aren't ORMs made to persist domain entities without intermediate mapping?

Comment: They could do, but the point of the repository pattern (I think!) is that I can switch it out for a different implementation. If microsoft stop's support EF then I can just use a different ORM.

Comment: Don't you use POCOs as entities? They don't have any relationship to EF and you could use the same entities with another ORM that supports POCOs as well.

Comment: I might be getting confused. I'm using POCO objects in my domain layer, and I'm using automapper to map them to the EF objects. I don't consider the EF objects to be POCO. I could easily be wrong on this!

Comment: If your EF entities are derived from the `EntityObject` class then you are right, those are not POCOs and have a direct dependency on EF. But you *can* use POCOs with EF, i.e. entity classes that are not derived from anything EF specific (just google "Entity Framework POCO" or similar). The EF team discourages the use of `EntityObject` and recommends the use of POCOs. Do you know `DbContext` in contrast to `ObjectContext` that you are using? I also suggest to get familiar with it because it simplifies the usage of EF in many aspects.

Comment: I did know it could but I assumed you need to make all your entity properties as virtual which appears to be a leaky abstraction, but maybe not. Also how do you deal with impedance mismatch? For example my book has a value object called ISBN. The value object does all the validation for the checksum etc. I would obviously want the ISBN persisted as part of the book entity however.

Comment: Do you have a distributed application, or you just not use a repository and have EF be your DAL?

Comment: It's not distributed, EF is just the DAL for my Repository

Comment: @RossDargan RE "Attaching this to EF would cause an exception as the key has already been saved" I encounter this same problem. It compels me to abstract out those infrastructure concern, EF often leaks(instead of working invisibly on your behalf) to your domain. I tried creating my own repository for that problem. I named it [ToTheEfnhX](https://github.com/MichaelBuen/ToTheEfnhX). Already has support for both EF and NH. Despite the name, ToTheEfnhX can be used on other ORMs, ToTheEfnhX are just collection of repository interfaces to implement

Answer (score 1):

Like trailmax said, it looks like you've got multiple data contexts.  I would shoot for one data context.  This can be done by creating a generic repository.  Assuming that you have a 1:1 relationship between entity and repository, this article may help you achieve your goal: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application.

Comment: I only have 1 context. In my test UI app I create a repository, and pass it to the service. This unfortunately isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I completely misread your question, I think your problem is multiple instances of DatabaseContext object. If you get an object from one context instance, then try to work with it in different instance of context, you will get a lot of exceptions: second context instance will see that the object is already attached, but it can't work with it, cause it is attached to the different context instance.

If you have only one context instance that manages your attached objects, it would see the object already attached and will just work with it. And you you won't need to clone objects with AutoMapper (nice technique by the way for member-wise clone!) into a new instances and any other horrible "TryingToAttachObject" stuff.

I had a lot of similar problems with multiple context instances until I discovered Dependency Injection and it's magic: it would create one instance of DBContext and will use it for all your requests and EF management.

Comment: Hi, as I have just replied to BigDaddy there is only one instance of the context, this doesn't solve it I'm afraid.